# ejabberd can not set nickname when add roster sometimes

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework

I am using iOS xmppframework and ejabberd as the xmpp server.When I add rosters with nickname, sometimes I can set the nick, sometimes I can not set nick. The packets I sent to the server are:

```
2015-07-03 10:19:24:144 pigai[36644:3a0b] The nick is songxiao
2015-07-03 10:19:24:144 pigai[36644:3a0b] SEND: <iq type="set" xmlns="jabber:client" id="roster-remotely-managed"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster"><item jid="xh1@192.168.1.67" name="songxiao"/></query></iq>
2015-07-03 10:19:24:144 pigai[36644:800b] SEND: <presence type="subscribe" to="xh1@192.168.1.67"><x xmlns="vcard-temp:x:update"><photo>c769b958f910fb6bfde4e8131385cc5ad2d95e0b</photo></x></presence>
2015-07-03 10:19:24:576 pigai[36644:3a0b] RECV: <iq xmlns="jabber:client" from="test3@192.168.1.67" to="test3@192.168.1.67/iPhone" id="push2270407375" type="set"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster" ver="6e3b72a923e4574fac87e8e89f08eee251cf73c8"><item subscription="none" name="songxiao" jid="xh1@192.168.1.67"/></query></iq>
2015-07-03 10:19:24:576 pigai[36644:3a0b] RECV: <r xmlns="urn:xmpp:sm:3"/>
2015-07-03 10:19:24:576 pigai[36644:3a0b] RECV: <iq xmlns="jabber:client" from="test3@192.168.1.67" to="test3@192.168.1.67/iPhone" id="roster-remotely-managed" type="result"/>
2015-07-03 10:19:24:577 pigai[36644:3a0b] RECV: <r xmlns="urn:xmpp:sm:3"/>
2015-07-03 10:19:24:577 pigai[36644:3a0b] RECV: <iq xmlns="jabber:client" from="test3@192.168.1.67" to="test3@192.168.1.67/iPhone" id="push2639732641" type="set"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster" ver="b16ad5f42baf7c0fe11925ed879ac7ecb0bcfb85"><item ask="subscribe" subscription="none" jid="xh1@192.168.1.67"/></query></iq>
2015-07-03 10:19:26:602 pigai[36644:433] RECV: <r xmlns="urn:xmpp:sm:3"/>
2015-07-03 10:19:26:602 pigai[36644:433] SEND: <a xmlns="urn:xmpp:sm:3" h="15"/>
2015-07-03 10:19:26:808 pigai[36644:4b17] SEND: <a xmlns="urn:xmpp:sm:3" h="15"/>
```

The nick was not set. From the client side, the nick is null. From the server side, the nick is not stored in the database.

Comment: Which version of ejabberd are you using ?

Comment: The ejabberd version is 15.04.

Comment: because my user's jid are numbers. I can not show the number in the user's roster view. That's why nick name is very important. This problem has block me for a whole week. I am eager for the solution.

Comment: Because I send an IQ and Presence to server at the same time. I guess the server may handle the two messages in wrong sequence. Maybe the server is handling the IQ writing the nick to database, but not finished. Then handle the Presence while reading the nick from the database, but there is no nick there. Maybe it is not thread-safe? Btw, I am using MySql as the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sequence that should work fine:

1. Send the presence subscribe.
2. Wait for reply.
3. Set the name on roster item.

We will have a look to see if we can improve to handle this case better as well.

Comment: I guess that why when I sent set nick name iq message again, then the nick name was set successfully. Thanks a lot.