# Nick name not set while add on roster to user

Tags: ios, swift3, ejabberd, xmppframework

In XMPP framework when i am try to add user in my roster with Nick name at that time user added in my roster but nick name not set in my roster list for that user.

Code : Swift 3.0 ,
Server : ejabberd

Snippets of code :

```
   self.xmppRoster.addUser(phJID, withNickname: strName)
   self.xmppRoster!.acceptPresenceSubscriptionRequest(from: phJID, andAddToRoster: true)
```

if i have tried manually and then i have received below error message.

```
self.xmppRoster.setNickname(strName, forUser: phJID)
```

Error Msg :

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="error"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster"><item jid="2323232323@ServerIP"/></query><error code="400" type="modify"><bad-request xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/><text xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas" lang="en">Missing attribute 'id' in tag &lt;iq/&gt; qualified by namespace 'jabber:client'</text></error></iq>
```

Below Stack Question i have checked.

1) [ejabberd can not set nickname when add roster sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31197590/ejabberd-can-not-set-nickname-when-add-roster-sometimes)

Help is needed.

Comment: which version of ejabberd you are using?

Comment: @ViniApp ejabberd version is 17.x beta,
let me know your points

Comment: Please check this https://www.ejabberd.im/forum/28666/unsuccessful-user-registration-ejabberd-server

Comment: Hi @ViniApp
Would you please explain me what things are wrong in my case? I am not understand your given forum points.